# Do Device.getSystemColors() need to be disposed in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I understand that colors creating using `new Color()` need to be disposed manually. What about colors obtained via `Device.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_... )`? do they need to be disposed as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you must **not** dispose of these colors.

Comment: great. so swt will handle these?

Comment: Yes SWT disposes of them

Comment: @greg-449 Although your answer is correct, please always try to add a reference.

Answer (score 3):

Just look at the [Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/Device.html):

> Returns the matching standard color for the given constant, which should be one of the color constants specified in class SWT. Any value other than one of the SWT color constants which is passed in will result in the color black. **This color should not be freed because it was allocated by the system, not the application.**

Comment: help.eclipse.org is currently offline. Please bear with us while we move the Infocenter to a more stable server

Comment: @user2790209 Google has a [cached page feature](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YG1rUERTb3oJ:help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/Device.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)

Comment: @user2790209 Eclipse servers are back online.